# How to get multiple same fields on one single field in same table using SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Example table 'meta_data' :

```
| user_id | meta_id | meta_value
| ------- | ------- | ----------
| 1       | 11      | abc
| 1       | 12      | xyz
```

Output :

```
| user_id | meta_id | meta_value11 | meta_value12
| ------- | ------- | ------------ | ------------
| 1       | 11      | abc          |
| 1       | 12      |              | xyz
```

My Query :

```
select user_id,meta_value11,meta_value12 
from meta_data 
where user_id = 1 and (meta_id = 11 or meta_id = 12)
```

Comment: Why is this post tagged javascript, PHP and Laravel?

Comment: [case statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)?

Comment: Please only tag your questions with tags that are actually relevant to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_id,meta_id,(case when meta_id = 11 then meta_value else '' end) as meta_value11, (case when meta_id = 12 then meta_value else '' end) as meta_value12 from meta_data where user_id =1;
```

You can use above query for your task which use case statements.Better if use `null` than use `''`.